# Google Mobile Analytics reporting wrong devices

Tags: google-analytics-sdk

I started using Google Mobile Analytics for an android app. Everything looks fine until I looked under Audience->Devices. Numbers were registered (small values) for Apple iPhone when we do not even have an IOS app. Any idea why this might be?